# Removing dataframe rows based on input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I was wondering if python has a function similar to LIKE is SQL. I want to delete all the rows where the value in the first column is ‘CLS’. The dataframe is 10 columns wide so if it finds ‘CLS’ in the first column, would It be able to make it delete all the rows which contain it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, this could be done by

```
df = df[df.<"COL NAME"> != "CLS"]
```